# Android: Adding a custom test to the compatibility test suite

Tags: cts, android-cts

I have created a simple test case using android studio that just checks whether the Device has WiFi Adapter or not and if it has then is it functioning or not. The test case is working fine on Android Studio but i don't have any idea how add that case to Android CTS and run it. I have configured git, downloaded the latest android source code for Android M. 
Thanks in Advance !! :)

Comment: You can first check already present test cases delivered by Google inside AOSP **/cts/tests/tests/net/src/android/net/wifi/cts/** directory to get a know how on cts wifi test cases. This test directory included tests related to WIFI manager. I am sure there are already test cases present in this directory that will be verifying wifi feature support in device.You can either add your individual test case by replicating already present test cases or make your own separate test file/suite.